# MS Access Export to .xls

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, xls

I am looking for sample "source code" to do this so I can create a button to automatically export all tables to spread sheets with the same name but with a .xls extension. I already know how to export tables manually.

Comment: turn on the macro record function, then do it manually. Bam, excel just made some source code for you. Read through it, find the relevant parts and go from there.

Comment: Since there is no record macro feature in MS Access, read the online help topic for `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Method`.  It includes a code sample.  Try it on your own.  If it doesn't work, show us your code and describe what happens vs. what you want to happen.  Include the full text of any error message.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion from @HansUp - Also, do some research on the DAO `TableDefs` collection since that's probably where you're going to get your list of tables to export.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested but something like this should work for exporting to all same workbook...

```
Dim lTbl As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim d As Database

 'Set current database to a variable adn create a new Excel instance
Set d = CurrentDb

strFile = "c:\FolderName\FileName.xls" '## Change to file you want

'Loop through all tables
For lTbl = 0 To d.TableDefs.Count
     'If the table name is a temporary or system table then ignore it
    If Left(d.TableDefs(lTbl).Name, 1) = "~" Or _
        Left(d.TableDefs(lTbl).Name, 4) = "MSYS" Then
         '~ indicates a temporary table
         'MSYS indicates a system level table
    Else
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, d.TableDefs(lTbl).Name, strFile
    End If
Next lTbl

 'Release database object from memory
Set d = Nothing
```

Or this for all separate workbooks:

```
Dim lTbl As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim d As Database

 'Set current database to a variable adn create a new Excel instance
Set d = CurrentDb
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

strFilePath = "c:\Database\" '## Cahnge to where you want to save"

'Loop through all tables
For lTbl = 0 To d.TableDefs.Count
     'If the table name is a temporary or system table then ignore it
    If Left(d.TableDefs(lTbl).Name, 1) = "~" Or _
        Left(d.TableDefs(lTbl).Name, 4) = "MSYS" Then
         '~ indicates a temporary table
         'MSYS indicates a system level table
    Else
        Set wbExcel = xlApp.workbooks.Add
        strFile = d.TableDefs(lTbl).Name & ".xls"
        wbExcel.SaveAs FileName:=strFilePath & strFile, FileFormat:=56
        wbExcel.Close
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, d.TableDefs(lTbl).Name, strFilePath & strFile
        Set wbExcel = Nothing
    End If
Next lTbl

xlApp.Quit
Set wbExcel = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

 'Release database object from memory
Set d = Nothing
```

Comment: +1 A good answer to a poor question. If there was a "Charitable" badge you'd have earned it.